# A href go on next page when i click on star rating input

Tags: html

On my page I have a table. In the table there is one `td`, in which I am showing average rating input. I want when I click on average rating page, the `href` goes to next page.

Can anyone tell me  how it can be possible?

Here is my html, but it doesn't work.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='supp_view_screen.php?id=$encrypt_id'><input id='rating-input' type='number' readonly value='".$last_cal."' step='1' class='rating'/></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code snippet for that :

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='supp_view_screen.php?id=$encrypt_id' target='_blank'><input id='rating-input' type='number' readonly value='".$last_cal."' step='1' class='rating'/></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

A good rule of thumb is:

> If there is no meaningful href, then it's a button

In your case, the element can either be a `<button>` element, a span, or even an image.

What I'm saying is that using a href here is not correct. What you're better off doing is using an ajax call to get the data from your controller.

```
$('#rating-input').click(function (e) {
    "use strict";
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        data: user,
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'supp_view_screen.php?id=$encrypt_id',
        done: function () {
            //Do something after its done
        },
        success: function (data) {
            //Append your data to the DOM
        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            //Do something on error
        }
    });
});
```

preventDefault will need to be used if you are using a `<button>` inside a `<form>` or an `<input>` with the type of submit.